# Weird artefacts in a matplotlib bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am using the pandas plot facilities, to plot a bar plot:

```
spy_price_data.iloc[40:,1].plot(kind='bar')
```

The bar data is plotted correctly, but the figure contains weird artefacts in the form of additional horizontal bars below the actual figure:

[image: bar plot artefacts]

What could be the problem here?

Comment: what is the output of the following commands: `print(spy_price_data.shape)` and `print(spy_price_data.index.dtype)`?

Comment: Those are presumably the tick labels, blurred and unreadable because there are too many of them.

Comment: print(spy_price_data.shape)-> (390, 8)  , print(spy_price_data.index.dtype)->datetime64[ns]

Comment: These are probably the tick labels. Surprisingly, when I plot other columns of the same dataframe over the same datetime x-axis as line plots (plot()) , the tick labels are automatically adjusted such that only hourly ticks are displayed. Why do both plot types behave so differently for the same x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'weird artefacts' are your ticklabels. You can even (almost) read them at the end:

[image]

The last value seems to say something like `2018-08-19 20:00:00`.
To make the plot more readable, take a look at the answer from ImportanceOfBeingErnest to the question [Matplotlib: How to increase space between tickmarks (or reduce number of tickmarks)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383314/matplotlib-how-to-increase-space-between-tickmarks-or-reduce-number-of-tickmar)