# How to increase space between tickmarks (or reduce number of tickmarks)

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

How do you increase the spacing between the tickmarks like in the plot below?

**Plot 1: Setup**

[image]

**Dataset**

```
time value
2010-01 1
2010-02 2
2010-03 3
2010-04 4
2010-05 5
2010-06 6 
2010-07 7
2010-08 8
2010-09 9
2010-10 8
2011-01 7
2011-02 6
2011-03 5
2011-04 4
2011-05 3
2011-06 2
2011-07 1
2011-08 2
2011-09 3
2011-10 4
2011-11 5
2011-21 6
```

---

**What I've tried:**

In the post [How to: reduce number of ticks with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682784/how-to-reduce-number-of-ticks-with-matplotlib), a user shows how to increase space between tick *labels* like this:

```
# Attempt 1
every_nth = 5
for n, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        #print(n)
        label.set_visible(False)
```

**Plot 2: An attempt**

[image]

But as you can see, the tickmarks remain untouched.

So using that setup, I naively tried replacing the `ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()` part with `ax.get_xticks()`, but with no success so far:

```
# in:
for n, tick in enumerate(ax.get_xticks()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        tick.set_visible(False)

# out: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
```

And there does not seem to be an option in the `ax.tick_params?` either. You'll even find *padding* there, but nothing about tick spacing.

Any other suggestions would be great! Normally I'd change the index to `PeriodIndex` and format the axis using `import matplotlib.dates as mdates`, but I'd really like a more straight-forward technique for this one.

Here's the whole thing for an easy copy&paste:

```
#imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')

# plot setup
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['time'], df['value'])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

# Attempt 1
every_nth = 5
for n, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        #print(n)
        label.set_visible(False)

#every_nth = 5
#for n, tick in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticks()):
#    if n % every_nth != 0:
#        #print(n)
#        tick.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tickspacing is solemnly determined by the difference of subsequent tick locations. Matplotlib will usually find nice tick locations for you automatically.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"time" : np.arange("2010-01-01", "2012-01-01", dtype="datetime64[M]"),
                   "value" : np.random.randint(0,10,size=24)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['time'], df['value'])
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you don't like those you may supply custom ones, via a ticker.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"time" : np.arange("2010-01-01", "2012-01-01", dtype="datetime64[M]"),
                   "value" : np.random.randint(0,10,size=24)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['time'], df['value'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((1,7)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%b"))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you really want your dates to be categorical, you may use a `MultipleLocator`. E.g. to tick every 5th category,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"time" : np.arange("2010-01-01", "2012-01-01", dtype="datetime64[M]"),
                   "value" : np.random.randint(0,10,size=24)})
df["time"] = df["time"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['time'], df['value'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(5))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")

plt.show()
```

[image]