# How to change tick labels in seaborn.PairGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-science

I'm relatively new to Python and programming in general, so I have some issues.
Recently I started reading 'Data Science Handbook' by Jake VanderPlas and I have trouble changing the tick labels of the x-axes in this example from Chapter 04.14 (https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/04.14-Visualization-With-Seaborn.ipynb):

```
g = sns.PairGrid(data,
                 vars=['age', 'split_sec', 'final_sec','split_frac'], 
                 hue='gender', palette='RdBu_r')
g.map(plt.scatter, alpha=0.8)
g.add_legend();
```

Some of the tick labels are overlapping and I want to change the amount of labels being displayed and maybe change the formatting from something like '5000' to '5K'. I tried to find a solution for this specific plot type, but my search didn't yield anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383314/matplotlib-how-to-increase-space-between-tickmarks-or-reduce-number-of-tickmar